# pytest-mock mock self method

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-mock

I'm trying to mock a self method using pytest-mock.

Simply my class got a function "distance" which I want to mock.

I want to test my **eq** function that is like this:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.distance() == other.distance()
```

I try something like this:

```
def test_eq(mocker):
    i = mocker.MagicMock(Interval)
    mocker.patch.object(i, 'distance', return_value=1)
    i2 = mocker.MagicMock(Interval)
    mocker.patch.object(i2, 'distance', return_value=1)

    assert i == i2
```

But this return:

> AssertionError: assert <\MagicMock spec='Interval' id='140333310434384'> ==<\MagicMock spec='Interval' id='140333310558104'>

I have also tried

```
mocker.patch.object(i, 'self.distance', return_value=1)
```

but this get me an AttributeError as i expected from MagicMock.

What is the right way to patch my object self method?

Comment: What you're comparing is if the two _mock_ objects are the same - they won't be that since you're creating a new one in your second call to MagicMock. Did you want to compare the result of calling `distance()` on both of them, instead of them being the same actual object?

Comment: @MatsLindh I edit my question, adding what I want to achieve. I just want to test my __eq__ function in my Interval object. That's why I assert i == i2.

Comment: Why not create two intervals that you know are equal and just compare them?

Comment: Yes I first try this. The problem is that I have to test a lot o things that I've alredy tested in my distance() method. So I don't want to write a lot of test for __eq__ since I just know that it depends on distance().

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can patch 'Interval' like this. Instead you should patch the constructor and manually replace the distance functions to return expected results.

This example will only test the `Interval.__eq__` method:

```py
def test_eq(mocker):
    # Mock constructor as it is already tested elsewhere
    mocker.patch.object(Interval, "__init__", return_value=None)

    i1 = Interval()
    i1.distance = lambda: 1

    i2 = Interval()
    i2.distance = lambda: 1

    assert i1 == i2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock out the distance method like this.
Assuming that your `Interval` class is defined in the interval module for example like this:

```
class Interval:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.distance() == other.distance()

    def distance(self):
        raise NotImplementedError()
```

Then in your test you can just mock out the distance function to always return 1 like this:

```
from interval import Interval

def test_eq(mocker):
    mocker.patch('interval.Interval.distance', return_value=1)

    i1 = Interval()
    i2 = Interval()

    assert i1 == i2
```